# Split Worksheets By Criteria VB.Net

Tags: excel, vb.net, split, interop, criteria

I want to split worksheets with Diameter Criteria in Column C in a Master Sheet, My code is

```
        Private Sub Splitter()
        Dim xl As New Excel.Application
        Dim wb As Excel.Workbook
        Dim Source As Excel.Worksheet
        Dim Destination As Excel.Worksheet
        Dim SourceRow As Long
        Dim Lastrow As Long
        Dim DestinationRow As Long
        Dim Diameter As String
        xl.Application.ScreenUpdating = False
        wb = xl.Workbooks.Open("E:\Patches\Main_Master_VB.xlsm")
        Source = wb.Worksheets("Master")
        Lastrow = Source.Cells(Source.Rows.Count, "C").End(Excel.XlDirection.xlUp).Row
        For SourceRow = 2 To Lastrow
            Diameter = Source.Cells(SourceRow, "C").Value
            Destination = Nothing
            On Error Resume Next
            Destination = wb.Sheets(Diameter.ToString)
            On Error GoTo 0
            If Destination Is Nothing Then
                Destination = wb.Worksheets.Add(After:=wb.Worksheets(wb.Worksheets.Count))
                Destination.Name = Diameter
                Source.Rows(1).Copy(Destination.Rows(1))
            End If
            DestinationRow = Destination.Cells(Destination.Rows.Count, "C").End(Excel.XlDirection.xlUp).Row + 1
            Source.Rows(SourceRow).Copy(Destination:=Destination.Rows(DestinationRow))
        Next SourceRow
        xl.Application.ScreenUpdating = True
        End Sub
```

I receive error Invalid index. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x8002000B (DISP_E_BADINDEX))'
at the Line **Destination = wb.Sheets(Diameter)**

Appreciate your help

Thanks, Regards

Comment: Please turn on Option Strict. This is a 2 part process. First for the current project - In Solution Explorer double click My Project. Choose Compile on the left. In the Option Strict drop-down select ON. Second for future projects - Go to the Tools Menu -> Options -> Projects and Solutions -> VB Defaults. In the Option Strict drop-down select ON. This will save you from bugs at runtime.

Comment: The actual line from your code is `Destination = wb.Sheets(Diameter.ToString)` With Option Strict On it would be `Destination = CType(wb.Sheets(Diameter), Excel.Worksheet)`  Do you really have a worksheet named after all the values in the Diameter column?

Comment: `On Error Resume Next` and `On Error GoTo 0` I don't like to see this. We have nice Exception handling in .net. Use it. You are swallowing errors and never know what they are.

Comment: @Mary , Thank you for your comments, I will use them

Comment: @Mary, Diameter is a variable Which Contains the Different Diameters Like T10, T12, T16 which will be a worksheets named with the same T10,T12, and so on and each sheet will contain the data of its type (i.e T10 will hold only the data of T10) and so on, These Data are in column C Named Diameter

Comment: notice that this line is working in vba excel as : `Set Destination = Worksheets(Diameter)` but in vb.net we remove Set so the code is `Destination = wb.worksheets(Diameter) which the VB Does not accept, Also Ctype is not working, Thanks

Comment: @Mary, I want the procedure to create the Sheets with the Diameters Names

Answer (score 0):

Try `Destination = wb.Worksheets(Diameter)`

Comment: Thanks but I used it before and it gave the same error